# Changing CrudMethodMetadata at Runtime

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

CrudMethodMetadata provides some information (LockModeType, Hints) for Spring Data Repository query engine.

My question is that changing CrudMethodMetadata for a Repository at runtime leads to problem or not?

Is that a Thread based (ThreadLocal) variable or not? If it is not then changing at runtime would intervene all threads which is not suitable to send dynamic information at runtime to Repository.

Comment: This is internal API not intended to be manipulated from outside. Would you mind elaborating on what you're actually trying to achieve? On a user API level, I mean.

Comment: I want to add Entity Graph to my Query pragmatically at run-time. I am using a mechanism by myself according to that, I translate Objects (Filter) to query. In one filter object developer may ask of fetching OneToMany or ManyToOne relation of Entity and another not. Then I am looking for a way by which I can pragmatically (in presence of Spring Data and its repositories) add Entity Graph to my query.

Comment: To do this before calling Repository method like findAll(), I get metadata from target Repository and add my metadata which contains required Entity Graph for current Query. But I think until now I did not face a problem because I tested my application in a single thread environment.